# Converting .csv file to .mat file without reading the csv

Tags: python, matlab, csv

I have a python project that gives outputs as csv. These outputs sometimes can be large as 15-16gb. When I try to save it with scipy, ram and cpu can't handle the data and closes the program so I need to convert csv file to mat file without reading the file. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to write the MAT-file as part of the same Python process that generates the CSV file, or to load the CSV file into Python and write it out as .mat? Is there a reason you can't load the .csv file contents directly into MATLAB? Can you show the code you are using and the error message(s) that it gives?

Comment: @nekomatic I'm writing a program for endusers and they need mat file. I can't load the whole file because the file is too large for computer rams. Some of these csv files can be large as 15-16 gb. Thats why I need to create a mat file without reading a the file. Actually I can change the code a little bit and write data directly to mat file but scipy library keeps reading the whole mat file. That causes too much resource consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You can't do anything with the file unless you read it, but it's not necessary that you finish all the reading. I don't know all the details but usually you can use *fopen* and *fscanf* to read just a few lines of the csv file, process however you like and save the partial result, then repeat from *fscanf* for some more lines again and again.

Comment: Reading the csv is actually not my main problem. My main problem is writing data to mat file. While writing data to mat file scipy library keeps reading whole file that causes too much resource consumption. I need the write data to mat file while not reading the mat file.

Comment: @Jiraiya You will have to split the data in multiple .mat files with the scipy module, which is compatible up to the '-v5' mat file format, which *cannot* handle anything larger than 2GB. Or you can use a newer version of actual MATLAB to save to the new '-v7.3' .mat file format for large datasets. Actually maybe the hdf5 format is probably better for exchange between python and matlab (and everything else).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will look into that. If I split the data to multiple files can matlab side join the files in matlab?

Comment: @Jiraiya It's trivial to traverse and join the data in memory. In theory it took another single build-in function call to save the data in a single new file, although the file I/O performance could be really, really, really bad, maybe a hour or so, and that's how matlab works...